# AM PM Error in DateTime.now()

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a Button which captures dateTime and updates it in the Event Object's custom Fields ActualStartTime__c and ActualEndTime__c.

ActualEndTime__c can only be updated after ActualStartTime__c. The code for both are given below.

```
Event event = [select Id from Event where Id = 'some Event'];
DateTime now = DateTime.now()
event.ActualStartTime__c = now;
update event;
```

for ActualEndTime__c

```
Event event = [select Id from Event where Id = 'some Event'];
DateTime now = DateTime.now()
event.ActualEndTime__c = now;
update event;
```

but when I make a report there are some records where ActualStartTime__c > ActualEndTime__c.
[image]

I think this is a problem with 24 hour clock. The Users are using two different devices to update the event.Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Are these date time fields, or string fields?

Comment: What are the actual trigger conditions for each field getting updated?

Comment: these are date Time fields and There is no Trigger.

Comment: @J.Rosnovski is there any logic for which field should be set, or is that all the code in the button?

Comment: @NicholasSavini yes, that is all the code in the button.